# React use of HTML5 video tag controlsList attribute

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

Tried to return with React component this element: `<video ... controls controlsList="nodownload" />` and download button still appears.

There isn't a way to pass this argument (controlsList) with React?

Tried `htmlControlsList=` too

Error log:
Unknown prop `controlsList` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see ....URL

Comment: could you share a snippet ?

Comment: ```return (<video src={item.video_url} poster={item.photo_url} key={item.attachment_id} className="project-item" controls controlsList="nodownload"></video>);``` i tried this one. apparently the react ignore this attribute, and there is no doc about it.

Comment: Maybe there is other way to access element attributes, which rendered by React ?

Comment: in the meantime you can create a reference to the video `ref={(v)=>{this.video=v}}` and then in componentDidMount you add it in with plain JS `this.video.setAttribute("controlsList","nodownload");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for ControlsList API [has been reported a couple of weeks ago](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9594) and the related [PR](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/9940/files) has been merged just 5 days ago.

It should work in one of the upcoming versions of React.

Answer (score 5):

Until the problem gets fixed in React,  this how you can add the attribute

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.video.setAttribute("controlsList","nodownload");
}

render() {
  return (
    <video 
      ref={(v)=>{this.video=v}}
      src="myvideo.mp4" 
      controls 
      autoplay />
  )
}
```